# Значение дефиса в предложении

Tags: пунктуация

К кому из перечисленных в предложении относится содержание предложения после дефиса, ко всем или только к гражданам?
"Правила распространяются на организации, независимо от форм собственности и организационно-правовых форм, индивидуальных предпринимателей, а также граждан - владельцев электроустановок напряжением выше 1000 В (далее - Потребители)."

Comment: Вы имеет в виду тире или дефис? Дефис здесь один - в слове "организационно-правовых".

Answer (score 1):

Тире относится к "гражданам", то есть приложение определяет слово с неопределенным значением, с которым оно тесно связано по смыслу.

Произношение без паузы (поэтому такое тире иногда называют тире-дефисом).

Пример по теме:    Я увидел бабушку, Николая Ивановича – соседа по квартире, сестру Нину. За столом сидели хозяйка дома, её сестра – подруга моей жены, двое незнакомых мне лиц. На террасе собрались хозяйка дачи, её сын – мой приятель, соседи и их дети.

Из этих примеров видно, что приложение **может относиться к одному  члену однородного ряда**,  в нашем случае - **к последнему члену (граждан),** который выделяется из ряда с помощью присоединительного союза А ТАКЖЕ.

Comment: Да это-то то понятно, что к гражданам. Вопрос, только ли к ним. И вообще, это ли хотел спросит автор...

Comment: Только к гражданам, и по смыслу, и по грамматике. 1) 1000 вольт вряд ли устроит организации и индивидуальных предпринимателей. 2) Союз А ТАКЖЕ выделяет  "граждан" в отдельную группу. 3)  И согласование в конце: граждан - владельцев  (форма Р.п. для одуш. сущ.) к организациям не относится.

Comment: Так вот уяснение этого факта на мой взгляд и могло быть смыслом этого вопроса, хоть каким-то. У Вас в ответе не об этом.  Да и сейчас, что значит "вряд ли устроит"? Ведь получается, что их "устраивает" даже меньше, коли их туда , в потребители, записывают без подобных ограничений. )))

Comment: Насчет 2) и 3) - вот тут да, согласен в основновном.Но это надо бы Вам в текст ответа вставить, ибо не мне надо объяснять, а автору. Хотя про одушевленность тут спорно. "Владельцы" само по себе одушевлено, и граждан из списка никто не отменял.  Как идет согласование по одушевленности, если в списке и те и другие представлены? Я думаю, что такое "приложение к списку" скорее все-таки одушевленное.

Answer (score 0):

Очень трудно отвечать на вопрос, когда он настолько неряшливо задан. Вы своими дефисами все запутали.

Здесь один дефис и два тире, одно между "гражданами" и "владельцами", второе - в конце, в скобках.

Попробую угадать. Первый и последний случай больших сомнений вызывать не должны. Вот что касается "граждан-владельцев", то тут есть что обсудить.

Для начала это именно тире, поскольку для присоединения распространенных приложений, требующих в ином случае дефиса, этот дефис заменяется на тире. Дальнейшее уточнение термина (так называемое длинное, короткое и прочие виды тире) здесь не принципиально.

Тире здесь показывает, что соединяемые им части не ограничиваются сочетанием "граждан-владельцев" (в этом случае был бы как раз дефис), но распространяется на всю часть "владельцев таких-то приборов".

С этим понятно. Однако учитывая официальное, если не юридическое, содержание текста, предположу, что может возникнуть и вопрос по трактовке изложенного, особенно в части того, относится ли уточнение "владельцев электроустановок..." только к гражданам, или ко всем перечисленным, включая организации.

На последний вопрос я могу ответить хоть и субъективно, но достаточно уверенно. Речь в части присоединяемой "а так же" идет только о гражданах. Т. е. организации и ИП попадают в число Потребителей независимо от наличия у них указанных установок, а вот граждане - только владельцы. Во-первых, представляю смысл подобных инструкций, с незапамятных времен все подобные правила бюрократами писались для "всех организации и отдельных категорий граждан", а во-вторых, если бы присоединяемой союзом "а так же" часть ограничивалась просто "гражданами", а не "гражданами-владельцами", то пунктуация была бы иной (вместо тире или наряду с ним - запятая). Да и фраза скорее всего была бы построена по-другому.

UPD

Я не хочу переводить дело в принципиальный спор (это почему-то не приветствуется администрацией, в чем я недавно убедился), но не могу не сказать, что мне аргументация Sibylla по-преждему совсем не нравится. Возьмем очень похожую внешне фразу из другой области. Пример самодельный, но близкий к реальности.

> Правила учета выплаты дивидендов распространяются на организации,
>   предприятия и отдельных граждан - владельцев пакетов свыше 5% акций.

Если кто-то убедит меня, что в такой фразе приложение "владельцев" не относится ко всему списку из "организаций, предприятий и граждан" - буду очень удивлен. А пока не убедит, буду считать, что это контрпример для попытки привязать "владельцев" исключительно к гражданам исключительно на основании видимой грамматики.

Comment: А разве не может здесь тире быть примененным по правилу грамматики § 167. Тире ставится перед обобщающим словом, стоящим после перечисления, например:
Надежду и пловца – все море поглотило.
Крылов
Ни крики петуха, ни звучный гул рогов, ни ранней ласточки на кровле щебетанье – ничто не вызовет почивших из гробов.
Жуковский.

Comment: @Андрей, здесь нет требуемого перечисления. Чтобы не углубляться в детали, самое главное: "владельцы" - никак не обобщающее слово для "граждан" и "организаций", это уточнение, т.е. сужение значения. Этого уже достаточно, чтобы снять подобные мотивы для тире.

Comment: Я ответ дополнил. Это больше для Sibylla, но Вам тоже не помешает.